# Is there a webapp that can translate obscenities?

Tags: web-apps, translation

> Originally [Posted on the WebApps community](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75820/is-there-an-app-that-can-translate-obscenities) but they suggested it
>   might be off topic and that I should try here instead.

I seem to be seeing more and more articles that have great messages but contain lots of obscene language. This doesn't bother me but it bothers lots of people and I was wondering if there was a site like google translator that could translate obscenities out of a given website/URL.

I understand the contextual-based translation problem inherent in the issue I'm describing and that any such translation tool wouldn't always be very good and certainly wouldn't catch everything. However; I'm just looking for something basic so I can send articles to friends without offending them due to language.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to censor obcenities by translating them into friendlier words? Or is it also okay to remove these words or black them out?

Comment: Do either apps exist? The former would be preferred but the latter would be acceptable.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I just wanted to get the requirements clear in case someone reading this knows about or decides to write such an app. It's also a good idea to add some more details about the sharing process. Do you expect this app to host a cleaner copy of the webpage that you can link to on their own website, or should it copy the content to a new email message, or to a saved copy on your computer, etc..?

Comment: Good points. I can work with any of the scenarios you describe but ideally I would like to be able to create a link to any URL (like a url-shortener service) that when visited displays a translated version of the page. I don't really want to create a copy of the site but again... I can work with anything

Comment: Such an application does exist. It's called a [wordfilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordfilter), and there are wordfilters available for multiple languages.